# Delay the page rendering until an iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**We have the following situation:**

- We have a webpage (let's call it *Page A*) that gives us only the header of a website.
- We have another webpage (let's call it *Page B*) that gives us the content with no header and includes the *Page A* in a hidden iframe.
- When *Page A* is loaded it will get its own HTML and add it in an empty div in *Page B*.

All of this is working as expected.

**My question:**

Can I delay the page rendering of *Page B* when it reaches the iframe, wait for the iframe to load and when the HTML is populated in *Page A* to continue the rendering. The behaviour should be as if I'm calling the contents from a synchronous AJAX call. The idea is NOT to show the content of the Page below the main menu until the menu HTML is populated.

**The business logics behind this:**

We're using an external service as a forum and we need to add our website header above. They can give as a free-html slot where we can put our own HTML. The header is dynamic so we need to load it each time from an URL. Since their site may response faster we don't want the content to load and several moments later the menu to pop out of nowhere. We need to have the menu HTML populated before we continue showing the content. The Menu HTML is populated from an iFrame by the iFrame so we need to wait for it to load.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can hide the contents of Page B via style="display:none;" and then show the contents when iframe's load event fires.

Comment: styles in a parent page can't affect an `<iframe>`, but if you have access to the `<iframe>`'s stylesheets this might work

Answer (score 0):

Insert the markup for the `<iframe>` dynamically in a content loaded event handler. Since you've tagged the question `jquery`

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var iframe = $("iframe").attr("src",url).whatever();
    $("whatever selector").append(iframe);

})
```